# Checking .val() in an if statement and using $(this) on object if empty (jQuery)

Tags: jquery, if-statement, this

I'm trying to simplify my jQuery code by not having to include my object id more than once per if statement. I've tried a few solutions but none seem to do the trick.  Basically I have a form for registration and an if statement during submission to check if there are any problems with the field (it's blank, for instance).  I just want to have the if statement refer to the input value, and if it's blank, use "this" to give focus back to the input.  Here's my code so far:

```
if ($("#first_name").val()=="") {
    $("#first_name").focus();
    return false;
}
```

This works as is, but I'd like to get rid of the second reference to #first_name and just use "this" instead.  Is this possible?  Ideally it would look something like this:

```
if ($("#first_name").val()=="") {
    $(this).focus();
    return false;
}
```

I know it doesn't work because the if statement is looking at val(), how do I make it look at the object instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`this` only works when some sort of calling infrastructure has set `this` for you to be what you want (usually in a callback function).  Your usage case will not do that for you as `this` will already have a value in whatever function you're in and there are no callbacks being used here that might change the value inside the callback.

Your best option to avoid evaluating the selector twice is to simply cache it in a local variable which is a widely used and simple optimization.

```
var item = $("#first_name");
if (!item.val()) {
    item.focus();
    return false;
}
```

Comment: That's just as good for my purposes.  I can even make an array of objects to check all the fields and give focus if any are blank.  Thanks for the advice.